# Android - hardkey menu item custom selector

Tags: android, android-menu, android-styles

How can I change item selector for hardkey menu? I was able to set custom item selector for actionbar menu. Unfortunately some devices with hardkey menu(like Nexus S) create different menu style. I want to replace default blue highlight selector with my custom red. I searched topics here and elsewhere without success.  ICS+ compatibility is enough.